# Winforms - best directory / project structure

Tags: c#, winforms

Wanted to see peoples thoughts on best way to organize directory and project structure on a project / solution for a winforms C# app.

Most people agree its best to seperate view, business logic, data objects, interfaces but wanted to see how different people tackle this.  In addition, isolate third party dependencies into implementation projects and then have interface exported projects that consumers reference

View.csproj

BusinessLogic.csproj

Data.csproj

CalculatorService.Exported.csproj (interfaces)

CalculatorService.MyCalcImpl.csproj (one implementation)

CalculatorService.MyCalcImpl2.csproj (another implementation)

Also, in terms of folder structure, what is better nesting:

Interfaces
---IFoo
---IData
Impl
---Foo
---Data

or

Product
---Interfaces/IProduct
---Impl/Product
Foo
---Impl/Foo
---Interfaces/IFoo

All trying to push for decoupled dependencies on abstractions and quick ability to changed implementations.

Thoughts? Best practices?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For me it depends on the model I'm following. If I'm using MVC it would be

```
Project
-Models
-Controllers
-Views
```

Or for MVP it would be

```
Project
-Models
-Presenters
-Views
```

Under the views I seperate them into namespaces relevant to the controllers, i.e. if I have a controller to handle inventory transactions I might have it as

```
Project
-Models
--Inventory
-Controllers
--Inventory
---TransactionsController.cs
-Views
--Inventory
---Transactions
----EditTransactionsView.dfm
```

For interfaces I put the interface in the same directory as the implementations.

Answer (score 8):

Bit of a late answer but may as well chime in.

I have been personally using folders based on the actual type of item it is. For example:

```
- Project
    + Forms
    + Classes
    + UserControls
    + Resources
    + Data
```

So I end up with:

```
new Forms.AboutForm().ShowDialog();
Controls.Add(new Controls.UberTextBox());
```

Answer (score 0):

We usually keep SourceSafe projects, project names, namespaces and directory structures in sync.

For example, given our company name as XCENT the SourceSafe structure and the corresponding directory structure for App1 looks like:

```
\XCENT
\XCENT\App1
\XCENT\App1\UI
\XCENT\App1\UI\Test //test harness for UI
\XCENT\App1\Data
\XCENT\App1\Data\Test //test harnesses for Data
```

etc.

The UI project is named XCENT.App1.UI.cproj, and the classes within that namespace are XCENT.App1.UI

We work for many clients as well so work specifically for them is prefixed with their name. Client1\App1\UI, etc.

Everybody in our firm uses the same conventions and it is immediately clear where everything fits.

If it makes sense to segment logical spacing further we do so. Such other segmentation includes .Export, .Import, .Reporting, .Security, etc.